# React-redux NavLink не применяет css класс при нажатии

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

До подключения к redux store NavLink-и меняли класс на activeClassName при нажатии, после - не меняют. Точнее меняют только после выделения ссылки и перезагрузки страницы.
Сам код:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import './header.css';
import { fetchUser } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    state = {};

    renderHeader = () => {
        if (this.props.auth.user) {
            return (
                <div className="nav_menu">
                    <NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="selected_link">
                        Home
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink exact to="/logout" activeClassName="selected_link">
                        Log out
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink exact to="/profile" activeClassName="selected_link">
                        {this.props.auth.user.username}
                    </NavLink>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div className="nav_menu">
                <NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="selected_link">
                    Home
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink exact to="/register" activeClassName="selected_link">
                    Register
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink exact to="/login" activeClassName="selected_link">
                    Log in
                </NavLink>
            </div>
        );
    };

    render() {
        console.log('Header props', this.props);
        return this.renderHeader();
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, что `connect` метод библиотеки `react-redux` использует `PureComponent` для обёртки подключаемого элемента. Именно поэтому CSS стили не считаются изменениями компонента. Всё что нужно - это отключить опцию pure в методе connect при подключении компонента.

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, { pure: false })(Header);`

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо передавать в NavLink параметр isActive

Можете например создать функцию внутри класса:

```
isActivePage = (path) => {
    return location.pathname === path
}
```

Один из ваших NavLink:

```
<NavLink
    exact
    to="/login"
    activeClassName="selected_link"
    isActive={() => this.isActivePage('/login')}
>
    Log in
</NavLink>
```

Comment: Не сработало: сначала ошибка - добавил window перед location, затем в isActive={() => this.isActivePage('/login')}, т.к. была ошибка is not a function. В итоге это решение никак не помогло. Классы применяются как и раньше после перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: вы уверены что функция this.isActivePage выдает хоть раз true?)

Comment: и кстати {() => ...} это не обязательно

Comment: Понимаю, что не обязательно можно просто передать isActive={this.isActivaPage}, но т.к. вызов с аргументом, то нужна ()=>().

Comment: Добавил console.log() в функцию - выдаёт 2 раза false и один раз true. При нажатии на ссылку сообщение немедленно не выводится, а только после перезагрузки страницы. Порядок true-false-true меняется в зависимости он активной ссылки.

Comment: может быть попробовать добавить параметр: className={isActive ? 'selected_link' : '' }?

Comment: @AlexanderP и да, по поводу () => () вы правы) протупил я:)